# How to distribute tasks to different PC in same network?

Tags: matlab

Background: I have an exe that processes image and write out result as a single txt file. To process, for example 500, images, I use Matlab to write a loop to call this exe 500 times then I got 500 txt files corresponding to each image.

Motivation: I'm feeling it's slow to run such procedure in a single PC to process large amount of images. I'm thinking to put the images in NAS, then connect several PC together and use Matlab to assign tasks to each individual PC to process a portion of the images. At last, all text files (results) will be collected to one PC.

Could anyone suggest what kind of toolbox I need, and any simple tutorial I can follow? Thanks!

Alternatively, any solution can distribute tasks without Matlab? Ideally, I don't want to separate images into different folders than access them in different PC.

As requested, the codes I run the algoritm is like:

```
for imageIndex = 1: numberOfImages
    % Call external exe to process a image with the index 'imageIndex'
    % The exe will generate a single text file like 'imageIndex.txt'
    system('myfile.exe', 'imageIndex') 
end
```

Assume I have 10,000 images, it's really slow to run on one computer (I have 4 cores, and par-for enabled). But I have another 4 spare computers. I'm thinking if I can hook them up so I can distribute tasks to them?

Comment: We cannot comment anything without code....who knows may be code can be vectorised and made further fast than the present one.

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to use the [Distributed Computing](https://au.mathworks.com/products/distriben.html) toolbox for something like that, although it may be overkill. You could also look at the [Parallel Computing](https://au.mathworks.com/products/parallel-computing.html) toolbox if you've got a multi-core PC, as it can offer significant speedups with the right setup.